# Make marker size proportional to data in scatterplot Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a scatter plot in Matlab
`scatter(xData,yData)`
I want each marker size to be proportional to a given array of data (`zData`), where zData is the same length as xData and yData.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
scatter(xData,yData,zData)
```

Comment: Yep, and you can make the marker change colour depending on a fourth input into `scatter`: `scatter(x_pos,y_pos,markerSize,markerColour)`